# Microsoft Office Scripts- moving to a specific cell

Tags: office-scripts, excel-365, ms-office-script

For Office Scripts professionals,
I can move from Tab1 To Tab2 through the script, but I don’t know how to move to cell A1 when moving to another tab. Any ideas  please

I try to link a script to a button to move to a specific Cell (Ex:A1) in Tab2.
I'm good to move to Tab2 but I can't move the cursor to A1 cell

Answer (score 2):

A bit of what you're using to go to Tab2 would help but I think I have a general idea of what you're asking.

After specifying the tab, you cause use .getCell(0.0).select();

Assuming there's nothing else on the sheet (saying that because that's all that's provided) it should go to A1.

Hope this helps!!